# Powershell a registry key via InTune

Tags: powershell, registry, intune

I've written a script to check for the presence of a key in Win10 registry and write the key if it's not found.

The script does actually work, however InTune dashboard is reporting that it fails.

Would appreciate some insight/thoughts.

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome"
$Name = "CloudManagementEnrollmentToken"
$value = ##REDACTED

Set-ExecutionPolicy -executionpolicy Undefined -Scope LocalMachine

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath))
{
new-item -path $registryPath -force | out-null
    new-itemproperty -Path $registryPath -name $name -value $value
    -propertytype string -force | out-null
}
else {
exit
}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you deploy PowerShell script over Intune? (there are several methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your registry path using either the predefined `HKLM:` drive

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome'
```

or use the long registry syntax

```
$registryPath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome'
```

so PowerShell will know you are trying to do stuff inside the registry and not of the file system.

See also [Working with Registry Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-keys)

Also, `-propertytype string -force | out-null` should be in the same line as the `New-ItemProperty` cmdlet, because otherwise PowerShell will try and see that as a new command (which doesn't exist)

```
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType string -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: Hi. Apologies, the version I had originally posted was edited. I've amended with the original data, which was as you stated, HKLM:\

As per the original post, the script DOES work, and they key IS being written into the registry on the target test devices, it's just InTune itself that's reporting a failure.

Comment: @Rob'Emrys'Brown Then, are those images the only thing Intune shows? No error message at all? I don't know Intune, but perhaps there is a way to have it refresh its data?

Comment: InTune at the portal isn't that great for diagnostics, I'm re-running and pulling up the logs from the endpoint to see if I can get a lead.

Comment: Got a little lead.

<![LOG[write output done. output = ((the script))
, error = -propertytype : The term '-propertytype' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.>

Going to take that out and try it again.

Comment: @Rob'Emrys'Brown Aha, then the mistake is probably because you have added the `-PropertyType` parameter on a new line instead of writing it it the same line as the `New-Item` cmdlet. (thought you did that for readability on the post earlier). BTW, if this is the whole script, you can remove `else { exit }`

Comment: Aah, too much copy pasta going on at my end I suppose, I'll correct that in the PS1 file and re-upload.

Comment: @Rob'Emrys'Brown Yes, please retry. I have added that in my answer as well.

Comment: It was indeed just the formatting after all that! Looks like the propertype part isn't even needed, the browser enrolls either way - but with it on the same line, InTune is now reporting success. Much obliged.